# BootReceiver class is not working and closes on manual restart

Tags: android

I would like to build a boot receiver.
Manifest.XML

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And this is my Receiver Class:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.e("-->", "BOOT COMPLETED");
        }
}
```

If i restart my device i get the message (on my device):

> the app xxx was closed

Comment: Please post the manifest.

Comment: look at my first post please :)

Comment: Is `BootReceiver` in the root folder of your package's source? If you're sure it's in the right place, you'll need to post the stack trace.

Comment: yes, the boot receiver ist in the root. the stack trace?

Comment: Check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this in your .manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="false"
   android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Also Try this out in your Reciever

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Also Add android:persistent="true" in to your manifest  tag

Comment: i tried this and i get an null pointer in my boot receiver on line  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))

Comment: Ok check updated answer if till not work then show me your log when app got crashed